# Delete files and subfolders in the folders "tmp" and "cache"

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want to use this script below to clean out "tmp" and "cache" folders in websites like "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1".

It tries to delete files and subfolders in "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\tmp" and "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\cache".

Which is right, but it also tries to delete files and subfolders in, for example, "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\MySpecialLittleProgram\tmp" and, for example, "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\MySpecialLittleProgram\cache".

Which is wrong. It should only clean up the "tmp" and "cache" folder in the root of the website and not in other subfolders.

If I delete the /s parameter in 'dir /a:d /b /s tmp cache' it will not find anything.

How can I do this part?

(I have deleted the /q parameter in the file deleting part and the folder removing part if anyone copies my script.)

```
@echo off

call:CleanUp "C:\Storage\Websites"

echo.&pause&goto:eof

::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

:CleanUp
    IF EXIST %~1 (
        cd /d %~1
        FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b /s tmp cache') DO (

            echo %%i

            ::DELETING FILES I FOLDERS AND SUBFOLDERS
            del %%i /s

            ::DELETING NOW EMPTY FOLDERS AND SUBFOLDERS
            FOR /D %%p IN ("%%i\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s
        )
    )
goto:eof
```

UPDATE:

I updated my code to be (it is working now):

```
@echo off

call:CleanUp "C:\Storage\Web"
call:CleanUp "C:\Storage\Web-IIS"

goto:eof

::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

:CleanUp
IF EXIST %~1 (
   cd /d %~1

   FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') DO (
      IF EXIST %%i\tmp (
         del %%i\tmp /s /q
         FOR /D %%p IN ("%%i\tmp\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
      )

      IF EXIST %%i\cache (
         del %%i\cache /s /q
         FOR /D %%p IN ("%%i\cache\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
      )
   )
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should remove the files in those two locations:

```
@echo off
del "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\tmp\*.*" /a /s
del "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\cache\*.*" /a /s
```

From your comment, this may be what you need to do: remove the `echo` keyword after testing it to see the commands on the console that would be executed.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Storage\Websites"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
   for %%b in (tmp cache) do (
      pushd "%%~fa\%%b" 2>nul && (echo rd /s /q "%%~fa\%%b" 2>nul & popd)
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: I have MANY sites therefore I need a script like the one I have written. It only needs to delete "tmp" and "cache" in the root of the website. It also (wrongly) deletes matching folders in subfolders like "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\SUBFOLDER\tmp\" or "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\SUBFOLDER\cache\".

Can you improve my existing script so it works? :-)

Comment: Explain where your list of many sites is coming from and where the folders can be - it will help to understand how to fix your issue. It's seldom useful to read code that doesn't work - because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `rmdir` or `rd` for this task:

```
rd "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\tmp" /S /Q
md "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\tmp"

rd "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1\cache" /S /Q
md "C:\Storage\Websites\Site1"
```

Command `rd` with options `/S` for all subdirectories and `/Q` for quiet deletes also `tmp` and `cache`, but those 2 directories can be easily recreated using command `md` although I'm quite sure that this would not be really necessary here as the application creating `tmp` and `cache` would do it also automatically.

If that is not what you want, please show as directory listings with files and folders in one of the two directories before cleanup and after cleanup.